# Getting own attributes / reflection?

Tags: c#

I search for a way to get an own attribute within a property.

Let me demonstrate what I'm searching

I want to use a property for float/double values to give a tolerence for comparision.

e.g.

```
[FieldAttribute(CompareTolerance = 0.001)]
public float SomeProperty
{
    get { return this.someProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (Math.Abs(someProperty- value) > 0.001) // here i would like to use somthing like '> FieldAttribute.CompareTolerance'
        this.someProperty = value;
    }
}
```

From another class i would use

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = someobject.GetType().GetProperty("SomeProperty");
if (null != propertyInfo)
{
    Attribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof (FieldAttribute));
    FieldAttribute fieldAttribute = attribue as FieldAttribute;
    return fieldAttribute.CompareTolerance;
}


...
```

So in the end i would only need

```
if(Math.Abs(someProperty - value) < someobject.CompareTolerance("SomeField")) ... values are equal
```

But is there a way to get an atribute within a property without using reflection each time ( this.CompareTolerance("SomeField") )

Comment: Not really. An attribute you have to explicity code against in the property seems stupid to me. Instead of writing the constant into the attribute write it into the code you have to write anyway. If you like to have it via an attribute you could go the AOP road and use something like Postsharp. There you could create an attribute that would inject the proper code at compiletime so that reflection wouldn't be necessary. And if done right special coding in the property won't be necessary also.

Comment: I would not only like to use it within the attribute, but also in other classes who possible to a comparision with the property. It is for only defining something like a tolerance ONCE for a value and use the tolerance in different places (e.g. for comparing something to the property, but not setting it) To use the value twice seems like a source of errors for me. You will never know or notice if someone changes the attribute, but not the setter, or the setter, but not the attribute. If you create a second class with all Tolerances as static/const, the overview is missing.

Comment: Then i would say the returned type of that property is a float no more. Its a new type that represents a float,its tolerance and the proper comparision methods.

Comment: Not applicable. Properties are used from an ORM. Therefore neither the property can be enhanced to have an additional method, nore an unsupported type. Even if you think about a few hundred properies and always to a conversion about what to store in variable (the setter of a property would never need to set an object with tolerence and comparision method in this case, as this is the fixed part) it seems like a higher overload

Comment: You where saying some other may use it and a simple usage of a variable for the float to make coding easy would break that attribute behaviour because a variable to hold the properties value won't have that attribute anymore. But you seems to have a specific case that needs some very specific solution so you should at least mention the context in your question to get useful answers.

Comment: No, its a more generic approach. If you use something like a tolerance for multiple places, you should really use the same thing and not multiple things in multiple places. If you put everything (like min, max, default etc.) values in a return type of a property, you will have something which can not be used for most use cases any longer (e.g. you will need special handlings for ORMs, can have problems with Third Party user controls and so on.) But otherwise you should keep everything which belongs to one memberin one place.

Comment: Think about something like 150 classes with lets say 10 properties. If you put comparer/min/max etc.pp. in one class, you will have problems keeping an overview. You will always need to go back/forward in the code to find a value which really only belongs to one property. Changing the float to a type with such additional informations will have large impacts in usage (even if you derive from float - try some public frameworks like DevExpress or Telerik controls with own types...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way around reflection for this except maybe code generation. 
You could consider a [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) that generates a [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) definition of your class with the desired getter/setter (might need to be placed in partial methods) code after extracting the values with reflection from the attribute. Then compile again.

I'm not sure why everyone seems to be avoiding generating code lately. T4 makes this a pleasure in modern versions of VS.

Comment: Problems with generation: some/many (according to which peaple are asked) properties need special handling (e.g.  checking for a special date), therefore it seems that auto-generating classes will either destroy there added stuff. I don't think there is something like a "partial setter of a property" (thinking about the update case if a proeprty is changed.

Comment: that is the purpose of partial classes. you put the generated code in a separate file and the hand written part in another file. check out "partial classes" and "partial methods". i'll edit my answer with some links

Comment: If you generate the code and then need to apply something special to one property, next time on creation you will overwrite the changes (e.g. you add to one property also boundaries (or here dif. values to compare to), or a special format change to fit data in database scheme or ...). Regarding partial methods: If you have a Property you have: a) a method which returns something else then void - this is forbidden for partial methods. b) a method which is not private - forbidden for partial methods. Both would not allow partial methods. therefore I don't think partial properties exist in c#.

Comment: what about base abstract class with virtual auto properties and then generating overwrites for the props that have the desired attributes. I cannot design a complete solution for you but i think you have the tools to make it work for your particular scenario